# Como usar require_once en magento 2

Tags: php, class, magento2

Estoy tratando de incluir una clase de PHP en Magento 2.

Uso un require_once y creo una carpeta lib en la raíz de mi módulo, la carpeta que contiene la clase 'lib / Meli / Meli.php'

También intente en la carpeta raíz del proyecto 'lib / lib_web / Meli / Meli.php'

Todo sin éxito, alguna sugerencia.

Este es mi controlador 'Controller / Adminhtml / Action / publicar.php'

```
<?php 
namespace Uno\MercadoLibre\Controller\Adminhtml\Action;

use \Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class publicar extends Action {
  protected $_session;

  protected $_filesystem;
  protected $_directoryList;

  /**
   * @param Action\Context $context
   */
  public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
  ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        $this->_session = $session;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function _isAllowed() {
      return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Uno_MercadoLibre::action_publicar');
  }

  /**
   * Publicar action
   *
   * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
   */
  public function execute() {
    $appId = '123';
    $secretKey = 'abcdefghijkl';
    $redirectURI = 'https://example.mx';
    $siteId = 'MLM';

    //$path = $this->_directoryList->getPath('lib_web');
    //echo "PATH " . $path.'/Meli/Meli.php';
    //require_once($path.'/Meli/Meli.php');

    //$libPath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::LIB)->getAbsolutePath();

    $mediapath = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::APP)->getAbsolutePath();
    $modulePath = $mediapath.'code/Uno/MecadoLibre/lib/Meli/Meli.php';

    echo $modulePath;

    require_once($modulePath);

    $meli = new Meli($appId, $secretKey);
    $params = array();

    $url = '/sites/' . $siteId;

    $result = $meli->get($url, $params);

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
  }
}

?>
```

mi echo $modulePath, devuelve

/var/inetpub/example.mx/app/code/Uno/MecadoLibre/lib/Meli/Meli.php

pero no me sirve para el require_once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le comentare cómo resolví esto.

En mi clase, Meli.php agregue:

```
namespace Uno\MercadoLibre\Controller\Adminhtml\Action;
```

En mi controlador, agregue:

```
use \Uno\MercadoLibre\Lib\Meli\Meli;
```

Object Manager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$ml_session = $objectManager->create('\Uno\MercadoLibre\Lib\Meli\Meli', ['client_id' => $ appId, 'client_secret' => $ secretKey, 'access_token' => $ accessToken]);
```

Ya con eso pude consultar mi clase de PHP en magento 2